# dynamic references by sending it from the route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been looking at the documentation and some other questions made, but I have not been able to do it, I need to consult another collection for an objectId, but these collections come dynamically in the routes.

The collections come req, as they are from many different clients

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

```
//route

// example collection dynamic ssdf2451_users, ssdf2451_campus, ssdf2451_programs
router.get('/school/prueba/tipos/', async (req, res, next) => {
    let users
    let school
    let prueba
    try {
      
      const Users = model(`ssdf2451_users`, UserSchema)
      console.log(Users)
      await Users.findOne({ _id: '5ef56f70d19aea6e70c82a50' })
        .populate('schoolId')
        .exec(function (err, usersDocuments) {
          console.log(usersDocuments, err)
          // handle err
          prueba = usersDocuments
          res.status(200).json(prueba)
        })
    } catch (err) {
      next(err)
    }
  })

// Schema
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose'

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  
  state: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
    required: false
  },
  accountNumber: {
    type: Number,
    required: false
  },
  schoolId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectID,
    required: true,
    ref: 'schools'
  },
  campusId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectID,
    required: true,
    ref: dynamic
  },
  programsId: {
    type: [Schema.Types.ObjectID],
    required: false,
    ref: dynamic
  },
})

const User = model('users', UserSchema)

export { User, UserSchema }
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What is this "other collection"?

Comment: @Vishwak example i am consulting from the collection users, then i want to be able to consult other collections through the objectid, but the name of these collections are dynamic and its name comes through the rout, ssdf2451_users, ssdf2451_campus, ssdf2451_programs, this is an example of the collections that can come to me in the collections but can be different: x_users, x_programs, x_campus